# BMS shows wrong voltage, changes to 0 V under load

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion, bms, 18650

I made a 24 V, 4400 mAh lithium-ion battery using 18650 cells connected in a 7S 2P configuration.

When I check the pack output voltage without the BMS it's around 21 V (very low, undercharged). When I check the BMS output it's around 17 V which becomes 0 V under load.

I think the deep discharge protection has been triggered.

The issue is that the BMS is not letting me charge the battery.

Could I bring back the battery to a decent voltage using my 29 V lithium charger without the BMS, because the BMS is not letting me do so? I'm just scared that doing so might explode the battery or something, so I need some tips.

Comment: Depends on your charger, it might refuse to charge them anyway.

Comment: We need to know what your BMS is, what your charger is, schematic for both, how your measuring it and what kind of load you're using.

Comment: 3V per cell, the battery probably dead.

Comment: Check battery one by one ... and charge it (a little) slowly & separately (?).